# Imagem à medida em JavaScript ou jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Fiz um código em jQuery que ao carregar uma imagem (`input file`) escolho uma foto e essa foto vai para o sítio do `input`

Porém a foto não aparece à medida, fica desformatada. Não sei como fazer para ela ficar ajustada automaticamente.

Queria fazer algo do gênero como do Facebook, que escolhemos uma foto e ela aparece ajustada no círculo.

Como faço isto?

O código é o seguinte:

**HTML:**

```
<center class="m-t-30">
    <div id="profile-container">
           <img src="/assets/images/users/user.png" class="rounded-circle" width="150" id="profileImage" style="cursor: pointer;" />
    </div>
</center>
<br>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="imageUpload" style="display: none;" capture>
```

**CSS:**

```
  #profile-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
    -ms-border-radius: 50% !important;
    -o-border-radius: 50% !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important
}

#profile-container img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

   .rounded-circle {
    border-radius: 50% !important
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    document.querySelector('#profileImage').addEventListener('click', function (e){
        $('#imageUpload').click();
    });

   document.querySelector('#imageUpload').addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            $('#profileImage').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
        }
    });
```

O código funciona, só que ao selecionar a imagem, fica achatada.

Comment: Ana não quero parecer grosseiro, mas como vc quer ajuda sem colocar seu código na pergunta? Edite sua pergunta, coloque seu código, ai sim podemos avaliar o que vc fez e te indicar onde errou ou uma possível solução.

Comment: Pergunta sem informações,como vamos responder?

Comment: Ah sim...não sabia que era preciso...eu vou colocar

Answer (score 1):

A imagem fica achatada porque você definiu tamanho fixo quadrado. Se o usuário carregar uma foto horizontal ou vertical, irá perder as proporções e achatar, porque irá forçar que a imagem tenha 150x150 pixels (quadrada).

Eu sugeria que você usasse a imagem como `background` da div em vez de uma tag `img`. Isso porque fica mais fácil ajustar a imagem dentro da div usando `background-size: cover;`. Ou seja, não importa a largura da imagem, o `cover` irá tentar ajustar a imagem dentro da div. E com `background-position: center;` irá centralizá-la.

Basta retirar a tag `img` da div, adicionar as propriedades na div `#profile-container` e alterar o código JavaScript para alterar o background do elemento.

Outra coisa é que está misturando JS puro com jQuery. Já que está usando jQuery, use ele no código todo logo.

Veja:

```js
$('#profile-container').on('click', function (e){
   $('#imageUpload').click();
});

$('#imageUpload').on('change', function () {
   if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
     $('#profile-container').css('background-image', 'url('+window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])+')');
   }
});
```

```css
#profile-container {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
-moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
-ms-border-radius: 50% !important;
-o-border-radius: 50% !important;
border-radius: 50% !important;
background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/149/149071.png);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center class="m-t-30">
    <div id="profile-container">
    </div>
</center>
<br>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="imageUpload" style="display: none;" capture>
```